# What concerns are there respect to use a short-UUID-like type as primary key?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I'm thinking to use (on PostgreSQL v13) an UUID type (with `uuid_generate_v4()`) for my tables with high traffic, and the others with a Text type (as primary key) by using an auto-generated similar to `crypt(now()::text, gen_salt('des'))` (short UUID?).

What concerns are there respect to use this short-UUID-like type? Can it be considered a good practice? If not, what suggestions do you propose?

Let's suppose to have a table with various foreign keys (FK), every FK is an UUID type, then when we open that table we'll see a long sheet stretching horizontally, or when we make a API call returning a list of objects with their IDs, well it is not cool.

I was checking some API calls available on Net, and they use some short-UUID-like type with a fixed length of 10 chars, so I was thinking, how do they get that result without getting any conflicts? What about its performance? etc.

Comment: Why not use `uuid` for all of them? Btw: Postgres 13 has a built-in `gen_random_uuid()` function, no need to install an extension to get `uuid_generate_v4()` any more. I would never choose a data type over another, just because one has a more visually appealing representation.

Comment: Do you have proof that your (expensive!) "short UUID" is collision resistant? Do you really want to waste all that performance? For what gain? I recommend that you use a sequence-generated numerical key, or if that is not feasible for your use case, go with a regular UUID.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm not saying my solution (?) is the best, it is a proposal only where my lacking knowledge is evident, hence my current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't use a text type to store fixed-length binary data. For example, UUIDs stored as text take 33 bytes, while the UUID type takes only 16 bytes. Your "short-UUID-like type" is 13 characters, taking 14 bytes when stored as text. For a saving of only 2 byes and a risk of collisions, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I will take it into consideration, thanks. Secondly I've noted many API calls on net use keys like this `ZRgPP9dBMm`, and I'm sure they are aware of collisions, then how do they manage it? what's your opinion?